# Count Vowels in 2 strings with Android Studio on button click

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am currently working on an assignment with android studio that needs to do a few things.

1. It needs to display Hello in 1 string and World in a second string in a button click.
2. It needs to compare the 2 different strings and display if they are equal or different

I have both of these working just fine, the last part I am having trouble.

3. It needs to look at string 1 and string 2 and display a number that shows how many Vowels are include din the 2 strings

I currently have 4 text views setup and 3 buttons.

1 text view to display Hello
1 text view to display World
1 text view to display if the above strings are matching or not matching

and the final one I am struggling with which is a text view to display the amount of vowels contained in the first 2 strings.

I also have 3 buttons, the first button displays the first 2 text views

The second button is what is used to compare the first 2 strings

and the final button is to display the amount of vowels

This is the current code I have setup for the final button and final text view, I have messed with quite a few things and just haven't had luck. This one will load but the button press doesn't do anything on click.

No error messages at this time it's not displaying anything. I need to be able to compare string 1 and string 2 which are txt and txt2 and then display how many vowels their are in those strings which end up as "Hello World".

```
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(view.getId()==R.id.button2)
                {
                    String file_name=txt4.getText().toString()+".txt";
                    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int count=0;
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    try {
                        fis = openFileInput(file_name);
                        DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
                        String strLine = null;
                        while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sBuffer.append(strLine +"\n");
                        }
                        dataIO.close();
                        fis.close();
                        for(int i=0;i<sBuffer.length();i++)
                        {

                            switch(sBuffer.charAt(i))
                            {
                                case 'a':
                                case 'e':
                                case 'i':
                                case 'o':
                                case 'u':
                                case 'A':
                                case 'E':
                                case 'I':
                                case 'O':
                                case 'U':
                                    count++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Total Vovels Are : "+count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }




Full code:
package com.example.project3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt;
    TextView txt2;
    TextView txt3;
    TextView txt4;
    Button btn;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    String file_name;
    String strFileContents;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHello);
        txt2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWorld);
        txt3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCompare);
        txt4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOccur);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCompare);
        btn3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_hello));
                txt2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_world));
                }
            });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (txt.equals(txt2))
                    txt3.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_equal));

                else
                    txt3.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_not));
                }
            });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(view.getId()==R.id.button2)
                {
                    String file_name=txt4.getText().toString()+".txt";
                    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int count=0;
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    try {
                        fis = openFileInput(file_name);
                        DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
                        String strLine = null;
                        while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            sBuffer.append(strLine +"\n");
                        }
                        dataIO.close();
                        fis.close();
                        for(int i=0;i<sBuffer.length();i++)
                        {

                            switch(sBuffer.charAt(i))
                            {
                                case 'a':
                                case 'e':
                                case 'i':
                                case 'o':
                                case 'u':
                                case 'A':
                                case 'E':
                                case 'I':
                                case 'O':
                                case 'U':
                                    count++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Total Vovels Are : "+count,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not going inside if condition. It should be     view.getId() == R.id.btn3

Comment: I have the button declared higher up as btn3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);  if I change the Id to btn3 it doesnt run, it errors

Comment: I went ahead and just added the full code to the bottom, in case that helps

Comment: Hi, why do you read text from a file using FileInputStream, also txt4.getText() returns empty string in String file_name=txt4.getText().toString()+".txt"; so no file name

Answer (score 0):

The commenter is right, your code is not executed because of the if statement.

The parameter in the `onClick(View view)` method is always the view that was clicked, so in your case it will be `btn3`.  This is to give the programmer a reference to the clicked view.

Remove the `if` block from your method (or change the condition to `view.getId()==R.id.btn3` as the comments says, but it's kind of pointless), and it should work. In this simple case you don't need to use the view reference you get, since you already know it will be `btn3`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess i'm not fully understanding. I tried to edit the view statement but it's not working - currently this is what is set for the 3rd button that "should" show the vowels - count=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);